# Two java web application. How to allow users to use it across with their respective login

Tags: java, authentication, shiro

I currently have a web application say App C. which is using a LDAP login.

Additionally i have 2 more web application say App A and B using custom login against a DB.

All web apps A, B and C have common database. And we have access to change/rework all 3 apps.

Problem statement. Users of App A and B should be able to use App C and they should not be asked for login as they have already logged into A and B. So App C should allow users of App A and B.

Solutions tried.

1. From web app A. We wrote an service at backend which works on authentication of web app A. And this service internally calls App C and creates a session of App C. This is not a right approach and nothing elses works.
2. Create a common login mechanism to use an external tools for authenication or something like google login but we are nothing taking that route.

Please suggest any other possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two options:

1. Have applications A and C share a session (e.g. using the same web server),
2. Use external authentication like OAuth or SAML (as you mentioned).

https://shiro.apache.org/web.html#session_management